# I am trying to cancel erlang timer using Reference

Tags: timer, erlang, elixir

I create a timer with [`:timer.apply_after/4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_after-4) function

```rb
{:ok, ref} = :timer.apply_after(60000, Module , :function , [args])
```

the `ref` returned here is a tuple like this

```rb
{-6451215415 , #Reference<0.265269.0.1654156.8484>}
```

and I am trying to cancel this process before implement it, is there a way?

I tried

```rb
:timer.cancel(ref)
```

but it returned arguments error. How do I cancel this timer before the time end?

Answer (score 3):

This is surely possible and works as expected:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ {:ok, ref} = :timer.apply_after(1_000, IO, :inspect, ["¡Hola!"]) 
#⇒ {:ok, {-576460467744153, #Reference<0.2854054855.1602748417.47727>}}
# ... # after 1 second:
#⇒ "¡Hola!"

iex|2 ▶ with {:ok, ref} <-
...|2 ▶     :timer.apply_after(1_000, IO, :inspect, ["¡Hola!"]),
...|2 ▶   do: :timer.cancel(ref)
#⇒ {:ok, :cancel}
```

Comment: how to use this Reference 
 {:ok, {-576460467744153, #Reference<0.2854054855.1602748417.47727>}}
 to cancel the process
without calling it another time

Comment: The reference is `{-576460467744153, #Reference<0.2854054855.1602748417.47727>}` and *not* `{:ok, _}`. The code above clearly shows how to cancel it (the second snippet.)